# How do I sample data from a vector of values so their sampling order fits a predefined linear equation?

Tags: r, simulation

I have a vector of four entries for a variable (dep_var), with each entry corresponding to the value of dep_var in a particular year. I also have a linear regression equation from an independent dataset that modelled the continuous change in dep_var over several years. Now I would like to simulate the behaviour of dep_var over time using my dataset so that the regression equation of the simulated data approximates that of the independent dataset. My initial feeling was that I needed to modify the probability vector in the `prob` argument of `sample()` every time a sample is drawn from dep_var so that the discrete process mimics the continuous process, but how to do this escapes me. Perhaps using one of R's simulation functions might be a more efficient solution? So far I have managed to mimic the continuous process using rnorm and the variance in dep_var, but ultimately I would need to simulate only the values contained within dep_var:

```
#Regression parameters
slope <- 1
intercept <- 3

#My data
dep_var<-c(1,3,4,6)

#Years to be simulated over
year<-seq(1:10)

#Run the simulation
set.seed(123)
sim_vals<-rnorm(10, mean = slope*year + intercept, sd = sd(dep_var))

#Model behaviour of simulated data with year
mod<-lm(sim_vals~year)
summary(mod)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = sim_vals ~ year)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.3622 -1.1708 -0.2899  0.8022  3.5002 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
#   (Intercept)   4.0938     1.3890   2.947   0.0185 * 
#   year          0.8294     0.2239   3.705   0.0060 **
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.033 on 8 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.6318,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5857 
# F-statistic: 13.73 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.006002

#Plot the simulated data
#Black line is the original regression model
#Red line is regression of the simulated data
plot(sim_vals~year,
     xlab = "year", ylab = "sim_vals") + 
abline(a = intercept, b = slope, col = "black") + 
  abline(a = coef(mod)[1], b = coef(mod)[2], col = "red")

#Obviously the output isn't ideal as the simulated values aren't exactly the same as those in dep_var
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand "ultimately I would need to simulate only the values contained within dep_var". It sounds like you want to simulate around subject-level predictions of a mixed-effects model but you haven't fit any mixed effects model (and thus can't distinguish random effect variances from residual variance).

Comment: I'm really just trying to increase the probability of sampling higher values of dep_var with every iteration (i.e. year) of the sampling procedure until I'm only sampling max(dep_var) with enough iterations. Ideally, I would like to be able to tweak the change in probabilities between iterations so that plotting the selected sample against the iteration value gives me a linear regression equation that approximates that of the independent dataset.

Comment: My questions remain: Do you know the specific year to which the dep_var values correspond? Do you know the uncertainty (ideally the predictive uncertainty) of the regression model? I think your question is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The issue I have is that there is no way to get a sample with an intercept of 3 and slope of 1 over 10 years with numbers that range between 1 and 6.

Comment: This really isn't an R specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you want advice for simulating data with certain statistical properties, it would be better to ask for help at [stats.se]. This is more of a mathematical/theoretical problem than a programming problem.

Comment: @Roland, I know which years my data correspond to, though these don't fall in the range of years I intend to predict across. I should be able to get hold of uncertainty estimates for the regression model.

Comment: @AllanCameron You're right - in reality I would limit my simulation to the years that predict within the range of my data. The example I gave was to convey the general idea, though perhaps not meticulously thought out.

Comment: @Mr Flick Thanks, I'll ask at Cross Validated as well.